# Structure of the medial axis in higher dimensions

Tags: geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, surfaces

Suppose that $S$ is a compact smooth 2-dimensional manifold embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$, where $n>2$. The [medial axis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medial_axis) of $S$ is the set of all points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that have more than one closest point to $S$. Let $M$ denote the medial axis of $S$. I believe  that $M$ has Hausdorff dimension at most $n-1$, as shown by Erdős in this paper: [On the Hausdorff dimension of some sets in Euclidean space](https://users.renyi.hu/%7Ep_erdos/1946-07.pdf).

My question is: is it true that if $p \in M$ is a generic point on the medial axis, then in the neighborhood of $p$, $M$ must itself be a smooth manifold? I.e., can the medial axis be decomposed into a finite (or countable) union of smooth $d-1$ dimensional manifolds? I'm willing to make assumptions on the embedding of the manifold $S$, such as it being "generic" in a suitable sense, if necessary.

It seems that the statement holds if the embedded manifold is subanalytic, as shown in [this reference](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/B:JODS.0000024119.38784.ff?noAccess=true). In this case, the medial axis is also subanalytic and the medial axis can be stratified. I'm wondering if the same can be said if the manifold is smooth.

Comment: What you believe is not true: Take $S$ to be the unit  sphere in $R^3$. Then the Hausdorff dimension of the medial set will be zero, not 2.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, it should be has Hausdorff dimension *at most* $n-1$, as shown in the Erdős article. I will update my formulation. This does not influence my question, however.